# How can i relate two tables through another table which has one to one relationship in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I am having 3 tables A, B and C.
A and B has one to one relationship. B and C has one to many relationship.
My question is how can i relate A and C through B. For example:

A has columns a_id, message

B has columns b_id, a_id (foreign_key)

C has columns c_id, b_id(foreign_key)

How would i create an association between A and C through B in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [relational many-to-many table association](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html) using the `through` keyword in the association that refers to `B` and specifying the `foreignKey`, `otherKey`, and an `as` name for the relationships.

```js
// associate ModelA to ModelC through ModelB
ModelA.associate = (models) => {
  // A to C
  ModelA.belongsToMany(models.ModelC, {
    as: 'AtoC',
    foreignKey: 'a_id',
    otherKey: 'b_id',
    through: 'ModelB',
  });
}

// associate ModelC to ModelA through ModelB
ModelA.associate = (models) => {
  ModelC.belongsToMany(models.ModelA, {
    as: 'CtoA',
    foreignKey: 'b_id',
    otherKey: 'a_id',
    through: 'ModelB',
  });
}
```

To query the relationship specify the `model`, `as`, and `through` for the association.

```js
const result = await ModelA.findById(aID, {
  include: {
    model: 'ModelC',
    as: 'AtoC',
    through: 'ModelB',
  }
});
```

Comment: So if A and B have 1:1 relation, B and C have 1:N relations. This makes A and C have M:N relation? @doublesharp

Comment: That's correct, it's a many to many relationship.